# create a script for azure pim roles assigned to users

Tags: azure-powershell

```
$filters = "(roleDefinitionId eq '69091246-20e8-4a56-aa4d-066075b2a7a8')" -or "(roleDefinitionId eq '3d762c5a-1b6c-493f-843e-55a3b42923d4')"
Write-Host -Message "Start ......... Script" 
$getallPIMadmins = Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment -ProviderId "aadRoles" -ResourceId "fd799da1-bfc1-4234-a91c-72b3a1cb9e26" -filter $filters
```

can i use or condition in filter option
if yes how

i am expecting to get output from above condition if use or

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to get the Azure AD PIM Roles using PowerShell Script***

*Check this Script to get the azure PIM roles assigned to users.*

***Note***: Uninstall Azure AD module before installing Azure  ADPreview

> Module and Login with Azure AD Global Admin Credentials. *

```
        Uninstall-Module AzureAD
        Install-module  AzureADPreview
        Connect-AzureAD
        Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment -ProviderId "aadRoles" -ResourceId 15e217e9-19a5-4006-a9f1-f7e74d8b2a5a
        Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment -ProviderId "aadRoles" -ResourceId "15e217e9-19a5-4006-a9f1-f7e74d8b2a5a" -Filter "roleDefinitionId eq 'fdd7a751-b60b-444a-984c-02652fe8fa1c'
```

***Result:***

[image]

Comment: hi Venkat, we can use as you have shown but i have multiple rolefefination id from which i have to separate and produce a output

Comment: HI ty01,Here is the script to get the multiple IDs.                                       
$RoleID = "role definition ID","role definition ID"
for($i=0; $i -lt $RoleID.Length; $i++)   
{   
 $val = $RoleID[$i]
  Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment -ProviderId "aadRoles" -ResourceId "15e217e9-19a5-4006-a9f1-f7e74d8b2a5a" -Filter "roleDefinitionId eq '$val'"
}

Comment: it does not seem to work